# Affect Second Spinner Choices based on First Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

So I can see that there are questions about this, but not in the scope of mine. I am buliding an app for Android that has two spinners. The first has an array of choices. However, I am not sure how to affect what choices the second one has based on the first one. I know that you can put in

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

but I'm not sure how to implement this. I've read on this but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm also curious as to how I tell the spinner which array to choose, is it in the .xml or in the .java file?

Comment: how are u  generating arrays for 1st spinner and 2nd spinner

Comment: @Andrain Can you help me with my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    string selectedValue = arg0.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if(selectedValue.equalsIgnoreCase(string1)
                    {
                        ArrayAdapter<String> firstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, firstArray);

                        secondSpinner.setAdapter(firstAdapter);//
                    }

                   else if(selectedValue.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)
                   {
                      ArrayAdapter<String> firstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array2);

                      secondSpinner.setAdapter(firstAdapter);

                   }
            }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: just copy paste your code in eclipse or any other software. you can find your errors. @user123

Comment: thanks for paying attention ...take it easy ..I am doing the same kind of thing in my application it is working fine without error. may be I did mistake while copy paste ..sorry

Comment: Its ok buddy. i found such this type of error in your code so have to update my answer. but you should be careful before answering or blaming others.

Comment: It says for this line `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Red1);` that The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){}, int, String) is undefined @ShakeebShaheen

Answer (score 0):

If it's a String array you could define it in XML then use getResource().getStringArray() or declare it in Java.

In your listener for the first spinner, you could do the following to set the choices for the second spinner.

```
secondSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newArray);
secondSpinner.setAdapter(secondSpinnerAdapter);
```

Tested and working

Answer (score 0):

update the array list of second spinner in 1st spinner setOnItemSelectedListener

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    string str=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if(str.equals("spinner item"))//spinner item is selected item of spinner1
                    {
                        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array1);
                 //adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                 spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);//
                    }else if{
                   ArrayAdapter<String>adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array2);
                    //adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                 spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        }
            }
```