# i can't find how to link data between 2 spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

i wonder if there is a way to link two spinner on android in such a case :

"spinner A get" data from mysql after onCreate() , when choosing an option on "spinner A" i want that "spinner B" get filled with the right data , let's say "spinner A" contain categories and "spinner B" should contains sub-categores , in my database i have two tables : categories and sub-categories.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_racherche);

    spinnerCategorie = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategorie);
    categoriesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Chagrement des categories en background
            new GetCategories().execute();
}
private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Recherche.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Chargement des Categories...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_CATEGORIES, "GET", params);
            ..... getting data from mySQL database (ok)
            ....
            .....
      protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        populateSpinner();
    }
}
   private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).get("titre"));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>   (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
      spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerCategorie.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648489/affect-second-spinner-choices-based-on-first-spinner/18648999#18648999

Comment: i know that setOnItemSelectedListener can link both spinner , but i'm wondering how retrieve data for the second spinner ( too much requests to the DB ) , is it possible to get data for the first spinner that inculde sub-data for the second spinner ? ( for each category the list of the sub-categories )